# Show / hide <ul> on click in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to show menu on HTML. Currently it is showing all the submenu options. I want it to show the options of the clicked item.

Below is my `home.html` code

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-item" *ngFor="let page of list;let i = index" id="id{{page.link_id}}"><span  (click)="showsubmenu(i)">{{page.link_name}}<i class="iconn" *ngIf="page.flg[0].SHOW_ICON=='YES'"><ion-icon name="md-arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon></i></span>

     <ul *ngFor="let sublink of page.sublink; let j=index;"><li >{{sublink.SUBLINK_NAME}}</li></ul>


    </li>
  </ul>
```

By default the submenu options are coming, see screenshot below:

[image]

`home.ts` code below:

```
export class HomePage {

 list = [];submenu;
  json_data = [
    {"link_id":"38","link_name":"Contact","flg":[{"SHOW_ICON":"NO"}],"sublink":[]},
    {"link_id":"37","link_name":"Offices","flg":[{"SHOW_ICON":"YES"}],"sublink":[{"SUBLINK_NAME":"test11","SUBLINK_OF":"37","SUBLINK_ID":"10005"}]},
    {"link_id":"34","link_name":"Products","flg":[{"SHOW_ICON":"YES"}],"sublink":[{"SUBLINK_NAME":"Quick Patrol","SUBLINK_OF":"34","SUBLINK_ID":"10004"},{"SUBLINK_NAME":"Link2","SUBLINK_OF":"34","SUBLINK_ID":"10013"}]},
    {"link_id":"33","link_name":"Home","flg":[{"SHOW_ICON":"NO"}],"sublink":[]}
  ];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
this.list = this.json_data;
  }


  showsubmenu(index){

    this.submenu= this.list[index]["link_id"];
    console.log(this.submenu);
    this.submenu=this.list[index]["sublink"];
    console.log(this.submenu.length);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introduce a new property which will keep the opened menu index. With `ngIf` toggle show/hide the submenu:

**HTML:**

```
//First li
<li (click)="show === i ? show =- 1: show = i" ....>

//second li
<li *ngIf="show === i">....
```

**Typescript:**

```
...
show = -1;
...
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-syaivq)

Comment: Worked like a charm, how can I hide the (ul) on clicking anywhere aswell, currently it opens and closes from the same button, please guide

Comment: It closes from a click on any other li / menu. You wish to close from any where on the page?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="page.flg[0]=='NO'?null:true"><ul *ngFor="let sublink of page.sublink; let j=index;"><li >{{sublink.SUBLINK_NAME}}</li></ul></ng-container>
```

in *.ts, you can add

`showsubmenu(index) {
  this.list[index]['flg'][0] === 'NO'? 'YES' : 'NO';
}`

it would be better if you keep 'flg' key as boolean instead of an Array of string. And instead of 'showsubmenu()', you can handle the flg key value in html itself like:

`(click)="page.flg?null:true"`